# SlickJS slide not moving if scrolled fast

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

If you scroll fast with arrow keys, the big slide with picture stays in place, you have to move slowly to be able to see it. Read the documentation of SlickJS, tested "waitforAnimate" but didn't work. Also i'm thinking about setting maybe a delay before you can move to the next slide like that I can avoid this bug. Any ideas ?

https://codepen.io/jinzagon/details/gOrggNv

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" />

<body>

  <div class="panel-up" id="1">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <div class="close"></div>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; color:white;">FIRST PANEL</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-up" id="2">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <div class="close"></div>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 30px; color:white;">SECOND PANEL</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" style="color:white">
    <section class="games">

      <div>
        <a style="color:white;" href="#1" href"www.google.com" class="reveal-up" id='open'><img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=1"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a style="color:white;" href="#2" class="reveal-up"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=2"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a style="color:white;" href="#3" class="reveal-up"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=3"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a style="color:white;" href="#4" class="reveal-up"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=4"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a style="color:white;" href="#5" class="reveal-up"><img src="http://placehold.it/288x288?text=5"></a>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>


  <div class="ip" style="opacity:1; z-index:-5; position:absolute; transform: scale(1.2)">

    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445768593937-05a3f7832b68?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=700&h=500&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443363742879-63e3d75de2f8?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=700&h=500&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445964047600-cdbdb873673d?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=700&h=500&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446329813274-7c9036bd9a1f?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=700&h=500&q=80" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}


/*Slider games*/

.games {
  position: absolute;
}

.slider {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto!important;
}

.games .slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.top_slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Slider background */

.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.slideshow * {
  outline: none;
}

.slideshow .slider {}

.slideshow .slider-track {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}

.slideshow .item {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slideshow .item img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: translateX(2rem);
}

.slideshow .item.slick-active img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
  transform: translateX(0rem);
}


/* Panels */

.content {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.content.hidefor-panel-up {
  bottom: 20%;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  opacity: 0;
}

.ip {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -5;
  position: absolute;
}

.ip.hidefor-panel-up {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 10%;
}


}
.panel {
  padding: 20px;
}
.panel-content {
  position: relative;
  /*background: #efefef;*/
  
  padding: 30px 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.panel-content .close {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}
.panel-content .close:before {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}
.panel-up {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  bottom: -20%;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-up.expanded {
  bottom: 0;
}
.reveal-left {
  float: left;
}
.reveal-up {}
.nav {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}
.nav button {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
.nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}
.bottom {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('.games').on('init', function(event, slick) {
  $(".games .slick-current a").focus();
});

    $(".games").slick({
        dots: false,
        arrows:false,
        infinite: false,
        centerMode: true,
        asNavFor: '.slider',
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
    onInit: function() {
        $(".games .slick-track div:first-of-type a").focus();
    },
            
    });
    
    //  $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.games' ).offset().top}, 0);//
    
    
    $('.slider').slick({
    draggable: true,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    fade: true,
    speed: 900,
    infinite: false,
    asNavFor: '.games',
    cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
    touchThreshold: 100
  });
  

  
  //Panels//
  
  // Reveal & Close Panels
var revealPanel = function (buttonReveal, panel, buttonClose) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Reveal panel 
    $(buttonReveal).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).addClass('expanded');
      console.log('hidefor-'+panel);
      $(".content").addClass('hidefor-'+panel.substr(1));
      $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-'+panel.substr(1));

    });
    
    // Close panel
    $(buttonClose).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).removeClass('expanded');
      $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
            $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');

    
    });   
    
    // ESC to close Panel
    $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
          $(panel).removeClass('expanded'); 
          $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');
         $(".ip").removeClass('hidefor-panel-up');

  $(".games .slick-current a").focus();
         
      }    
    });
  }); 
}

revealPanel('.reveal-up','.panel-up', '.close');
//revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');

    $('#open').on('click', function() {
      $('.panel-up').hide();$('#1').show();
    });
    $('#close').on('click', function() {
      $('.panel-up').hide();$('#2').show();
    });

// Reveal Panel with Shortcuts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
        $('.panel-left').addClass('expanded'); 
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 82) { 
        $('.panel-up').hide();$('#1').show();
        $('.panel-up').addClass('expanded'); 
        $(".content").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
        $(".ip").addClass('hidefor-panel-up');
    }
    
     if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
          $(".games .slick-current a").focus();
    }
    
     if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
          $(".games .slick-current a").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding     `speed: 900,` to my first slide. Both slides need to have the same speed.